# SSRS 2012 Shared SQL DataSource throws error on other workstations

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2012

I'm having a bizarre issue with SSRS 2012 reports, specifically with SQL Shared Data Sources.

My reproduction steps are as follows:

1. Create a new shared data source called Test, pointing to a SQL server on the network. Test credentials, get a successful test.
2. Create a new report called Test, not going through the wizard.
3. On the Test report, add the shared data source.
4. Add Dataset1 utilizing the shared datasource 'Test'. Query type of text as `SELECT 1 AS 'one', 2 AS 'two'`
5. Preview report. As expected, I get a blank report with no errors.
6. Commit data source and report to TFS repository (.rdl, .rds and changes to .sln).
7. Get latest on coworkers workstation
8. Open Test report, and go to Preview. The error I receive states 'An error has occurred during report processing.' Refreshing the report also gives error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object,'

[image: SSRS error]
Recreating the shared data source on coworker's workstation lets the report run successfully again. Recommitting the changed data source then breaks the report on my original machine. The only thing changing in the .rds file is the DataSourceID, which is not referenced in the .rdl as far as I can see.

Both machines are on Visual Studio Premium 2013, with a SSRS 2012 solution file.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this are very much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security, datasource credentials are not committed to source control nor propagated when deployed to a server. The first time you use the datasource in a new environment you will have to re-enter the credentials for the datasource to be able to connect to the database.

Comment: This definitely does seem to be the case, thanks for pointing that out!

I am noticing a discrepancy though. When I set the credentials on a new environment, it changes the guid data source id, which forces a checkout. If I commit this, I think it then resets the credentials again on the original committer's environment. (I'll verify this in just a moment and update when I've confirmed)

BUT, we have two other data sources that aren't doing this. They both have credential set on different workstations without issue. Leads to even more confusion there.

Comment: So I verified that fixing the credentials on another workstation, and then committing .rds breaks the previously fixed credentials on the original workstation. Seems like a design flaw to have SSRS save a different DataSourceID when adding credentials.

We're getting around it by just using Windows Auth to connect to our sql source for testing purposes. Shouldn't have to change the credentials between workstations at that point.